# Dotfuscator has suddenly started renaming public members, even with library mode turned on

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, dotfuscator

It says it all in the title really: since updating Dotfuscator Community Edition to "v5.42.0.9514-e0e25f754" my library mode setting is no longer being honored: all public members of classes are being renamed, but the public class names are not.

My existing dotfuscatorconfig.xml hasn't changed in almost 2 years, so this is a new breaking change for me. Any ideas what could be occurring here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went the direct route (which I perhaps should have done before panicking and posting this to StackOverflow): I contacted Preemptive support, and they told me there was a bug in the version I was using, and that a newer version (October 2019) had been released a few days ago that fixed this problem.

I've updated to that version, and things are working correctly again.